# Detailed Request and response logging for SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, logging

Ruby on Rails provides default logging for "Request", "Response" objects in the controller as well as the time taken etc. Is there a way in which we can accomplish the same in case of Spring Boot without having to write the log statements to print request, response and time taken etc.

PS : Python's Flask has something like **Before** and **After** annotations, but I m not sure how we can accomplish Rich Rails like logging in Spring Boot.

Comment: In my concern no, but you can use AOP Aspect Oriented Programming to logging before and after generically on the methods that you consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        registry.addInterceptor(new ControllerInterceptor()).addPathPatterns(ControllerInterceptor.PATTERN);
    }

public class ControllerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public static final String PATTERN = "/mycontrollermappingvalue*";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before request");
        //log values from HttpServletRequest
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
        ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
         System.out.println("After request");
        //log values from HttpServletResponse
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for Java Aspect Oriented Programming.  Take a look at [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/simple-introduction-to-aop.html) example.

Here is an example of the config entry that ends up logging method calls.

```
<aop:config> 
  <aop:aspect id="aspectService" ref="logAspect" > 
     <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBeforeBC"
    expression="execution(* com.test.application.service.*.*(..))" />
      <aop:before method="logBefore" pointcut-ref="pointCutBefore" /> 
  </aop:aspect> 

  <aop:aspect id="aspectUserInterface" ref="logAspect" > 
     <aop:pointcut id="pointCutBeforeUserInterfaceBA"
    expression="execution(* com.test.application.ui.*(..))" />
      <aop:before method="pointCutBeforeTraceInput" pointcut-ref="pointCutBeforeUserInterface" /> 
      <aop:after-throwing method="pointCutAfterThrowingOutput" throwing="_Throwable" pointcut-ref="pointCutBeforeUserInterface" />


  </aop:aspect> 
</aop:config>
```